# I need to add data to a Googlemaps plugin from dyve.net

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've downloaded a JQuery Google Maps plugin from Dyve.net http://www.dyve.net/jquery/?googlemaps and added it my site eg. http://www.uksail.co.uk/category/company/sailing-clubs. I've got no problem adding multiple locations with individual info boxes but want to add a URL and other info such as a phone number and address as well as a 'directions to and from' function to each individual one.
Please view source of the above linked page to see the example data that displays the Google map.

If someone could point me in the right direction t'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with the Google Maps JavaScript API, and it couldn't be easier to integrate. I don't think you'll need a jQuery plugin with all the examples they give you.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/

Comment: Hi Seth, Thanks so much for getting back to me, to be honest I've got no idea about javascript and want to stick with the code that the developer of the uksail site put there in the first place cause thats what i understand for the time being. i'm going to head over to the link you gave me and maybe work out an easier way to integrate a map:) cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `txt:$(elem).attr("title")` on line 26 of jquery-googlemaps.js to `txt:$('.info',elem).html()`

Then update your HTML "geo" elements to something like:

```
<div class="geo" title="Plym Yacht Club">
  <abbr class="latitude" title="50.361409"></abbr>
  <abbr class="longitude" title="-4.109227"></abbr>
  <div class="info">
    Location<br />
    Phone Number<br />
    Address<br />
    Etc...
  </div>
</div>
```

You're basically getting the info window html from the "info" div instead of the "title" attribute.

Also, make sure you're closing your `<div class="geo">` tags.

Comment: SteamDev, Thank you so much for this invaluable answer! It's been driving me mad- I reckon I need to sit down with a jQuery book rather than trying to learn bit by bit... Really, thanks again and I'll sort out the unclosed divs as well:) Cheers

Comment: Steamdev, thanks again for the help but i've just noticed that the info is appearing below the map now as well- any idea how to make it show only in the info window? please see http://www.uksail.co.uk/category/company/sailing-clubs. Thanks again!

Comment: Hide your "geo" divs with css: `.geo {display:none}`